# AWS cloud9 emacs keybindings

Tags: amazon-web-services, emacs, cloud9-ide

I am using cloud9 on aws cloud and I launch emacs from one of the terminal windows, however the usual key-bindings are not working properly (I guess they are being captured by the cloud9 IDE). Is is possible to have the aws terminal behave like the terminal on my personal computer when running emacs?

Answer (score 0):

AWS Cloud9 is a **cloud-based** integrated development environment (IDE), You can customize keybindings, But that's for Cloud9 itself, To catch emacs keys, you should [run Cloud9 workspaces locally.](https://0n3z3r0n3.medium.com/run-cloud9-workspaces-locally-2398c64a6a82)

...or alternatively, Switch keyboard keybindings mode:
For more information, in the AWS Cloud9 IDE:

1. On the menu bar, choose **AWS Cloud9**, **Preferences**.
2. On the **Preferences** tab, choose **Keybindings**.
3. For **Keyboard Mode**, choose **Emacs**.
4. For **Operating System**, choose **MacOS**.

More on [MacOS Emacs Keybindings Reference for the AWS Cloud9 Integrated Development Environment (IDE)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/keybindings-emacs-apple-osx.html)